# How does IronPython loads modules while being hosted?

Tags: python, .net, ironpython

I'm confused about the way IronPython loads modules while being hosted.

I'm using IronPython 2.7.7 installed using the MSI package and I've referenced `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\IronPython.dll` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Microsoft.Scripting.dll`.

Sometimes IronPython fails to load a module throwing `IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named modulename'`, but sometimes everything works fine.

For example,

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now()").Execute();
```

works, but

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import json; print json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])").Execute();
```

doesn't.

I've found a suggestion to set search paths in `engine`. So I've added

```
var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);
```

and now the example which uses `json` module works.

But search paths which I get from `engine` contain only

1. `"."`
2. `"D:\\IronPythonTest\\bin\\Debug\\Lib"`
3. `"D:\\IronPythonTest\\bin\\Debug\\DLLs"`

And I don't have neither `Lib` nor `DLLs` folders under my `Debug` folder.

So how does IronPython manage to load `datetime` module?

Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic approach in adding the relevant paths to the engine is correct.

IronPython uses large amounts of the standard library (wherever possible). Low level modules that are implemented natively in CPython are implemented in C# for IronPython. One of those [modules](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/tree/master/Src/IronPython.Modules) is [datetime](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/blob/master/Src/IronPython.Modules/datetime.cs). So as long as `IronPython.Modules.dll` is around, several standard modules are available even without specific loading/path handling.