# Executing Python Code in C# WebAPI WebService Project

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, python.net

I am working on ASP.NET WebAPI Web Services and one of my requirement is to call a python script that outputs a JSON object and send it as web service response.

I have Installed IronPython 2.7.9 nuget package and my computer has Python 3.6

I addded IronPython nuget package in my project and tried the code from link https://gist.github.com/0x49D1/23196eb99b4c1f089b2033b6191e84e8

**test.py**

```
    import json
    data = {}
    data['1'] = 'value1'
    data['2'] = 'value2'
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    print (json_data)
```

**Exception**
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException
{"No module named json"}

Comment: Working with JSON is pretty easy in .net. Would the re-implementaton in c# be significant?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44441574/468244) ... You will have to setup the search paths in the engine for it. Your Python 3.6 installation should not matter and you should be using a library matching the IronPython environment.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Pythonnet and Python.Include from NuGet.
Code sample:

```
if (Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.IsInitialized == false) {
    Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize();
    Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads();
}
using (Py.GIL()) {
    ///
    /// your code
    ///
    if (Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.IsInitialized == true) {
        Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.InitExt();
    }
}
```